# using Literal in class globally vs locally

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to use ***Literal*** in my Default.aspx.cs (code-behind) to create html formats like

```
<br />
```

I found that if declared locally, it works fine:

```
        public void Populate_ProductList()
        {
         Literal lt = new Literal();
         lt.Text = "<br />" + "<br />";
         form1.Controls.Add(lt);
        }
```

However if I declared it globally:

```
namespace myprojectname
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private Literal lt = new Literal();  

         public void Populate_ProductList()
        {             
         lt.Text = "<br />" + "<br />";
         form1.Controls.Add(lt);
        }
```

The Literal simply does not appears (i.e. it does not shows a break on the html page).  Did I miss something?  Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add the same control to the page more than once, so when you go and try to add the same literal to the page over and over again its not going to work properly.  That's why it works when you create a new control each time you try to add it.

Comment: Does that mean it needs to create a new control for every Literal used?  Ultimately it would be better to dynamically create a table instead i assume

Comment: @Alex Probably, yes.  It's almost always wrong to add controls to a page dynamically like this.  You should really have all of your HTML in the markup, rather than in the code behind.

Comment: problem is my form will be different everytime i load it, so markup kinda limited the option i had, unless there's a way

Comment: @Alex There's virtually always a way.  What that way is will of course depend on what needs to happen.

Comment: The form i am working on loads controls (dropdown / textbox) depends on the DB's data I am connected to, and I would like to have a non-fixed table.  That's the reason I put everything in the code-behind.  Googled and that's most ppl's approach.  Please enlighten me if there's a better way, thank you sir/madam

Comment: @Alex You should be binding the data to a gridview.

Comment: thanks thought it's only avail for winform, will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own control (which extends from WebControl class) which renders line breaks.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LineBreaker lb = new LineBreaker(4);
        this.Controls.Add(lb);
    }
}

public static class HtmlConstants
{
    public const string Br = @"<br />";
}

public class LineBreaker : WebControl
{
    public LineBreaker(int lineCount)
    {
        LineCount = lineCount;
    }
    public int LineCount { get; set; }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(CreateLineBreaker(LineCount));
        base.Render(writer);
    }

    public string CreateLineBreaker(int howManyLines)
    {
        string result = String.Empty;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (howManyLines > 0)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < howManyLines; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(HtmlConstants.Br);
            }

            result = sb.ToString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does this seriously answer the question?

Comment: I agree with you on Literal control not the best way

Comment: Actually it's a valid answer. All Alex wants to do is generate multiple number of line breaks. Updated the answer. It's tested and fully working.